# Implicitly passing router history

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am making a web app with `react-router` that has navigation similar to mobile stack navigation. The content of a page is supposed to be wrapped in NavigationScreen object (that controls the sidebar, navbar and the works):

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <NavigationScreen>
         <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
           <Text>Home Screen</Text>
           <Link to='/details'>details</Link>
        </View>
       </NavigationScreen>
    );
  }
}
```

And the routes are made like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }}>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomeScreen} />
          <Route path='/details' component={DetailsScreen} />
        </View>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

But I think I made an error in the planning. I want the navigation bar to have a "back button", which should work by invoking `this.props.history.goBack`. The thing is that the `HomeScreen` class receives this prop, and not the `NavigationScreen`. The only solution I can see is making a rather awkward prop passing:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <NavigationScreen history=this.props.history>
         <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
           <Text>Home Screen</Text>
           <Link to='/details'>details</Link>
        </View>
       </NavigationScreen>
    );
  }
}
```

Looks pretty bad IMO, is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC on `NavigationScreen` if you don't want to pass `history` as a prop.